# Use Windows Phone ProgressBar untill HttpWebRequest has finished downloading?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, download, httpwebrequest, progress-bar

I am downloading 2 XML files with the code below:

```
    public static string GetXMLString()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"http://www.example.com/data/xml/2.0/"));request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        xmlKolosej = response.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    xml = null;
                }
            }, request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            xml = null;
        }

        return xml;
    }
```

The code is called via 2 identical methods as the one above (2 different XML files to download from different URIs). Both methods are called in a sequence when the Windows Phone page loads. Sometimes when I'm am on a bad wireless connection it tends to take a while to download. 
I was wondering, how would I be able to check if the HttpWebRequest has finished downloading the files and initiate a ProgressBar until it was finished downloading?
Do you maybe suggest a different approach to the problem?

EDIT - Additional info:
The reason why I would need to have a progress bar is because the data is needed in order for the user to advance. If the user would try to advance in the application and he was on a bad wireless connection and the data was still downloading, the method would of course return null. Thus the progress bar would lock the user out of the app until it finished downloading.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be your actual code, as the requests are async and this code first wouldn't compile since xml is undefined and secondly would always return null as the method would return before the request had run.

Ignoring that though, the way I handle a progress bar across multiple requests is to have a counter on my ViewModel that I increment when something starts some work and decrement when something finishes. I then bind my progress bar to be displayed when the counter is > 0.

Also be sure to use the PerformaceProgressBar from http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: The xml in the above code is a global variable, so the code in my example works and doesn't return null if the specified uri actually exists. `private static string xml = null; //implemented property for xml; public static string GetXMLString() { //implmentation - look above; }`
However thaks for the counter idea. Is there maybe an online example I could see of a similar implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right that code is not valid and wouldn't run on WP7. Here is some code that would though.

```
private void MyMethod()
{          
   //You'll want to execute this twice, one for each xml file
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
   wc.OpenReadAsync("{Enter url of XML File}");
}
private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Handle results here
   //Also you'll want to disable ProgressBar to show that the download is complete
   //Also you'll increment the counter that Chris suggested here
}
```

As Chris mentioned all requests are asynchronous in Windows Phone 7, so the easiest way is to create a counter variable and increment it everytime the "OpenReadCompleted" event is fired. At the same time you'll also disable the progressbar to show that the download is complete. Error handling like you were saying would also be handled here, except for checking for a network. You might want to do that before you even make a request.

For a full example on how to read xml files(typically rss or atom) from the web check out this post:
[Reading RSS Items in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/02/03/reading-rss-items-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).

NOTE: Remember that pulling an xml file from the web using WebClient works the same way as pulling an rss feed or atom feed.

Comment: Yes I check for a network before I call this method. `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` However if for instance you connect to a wireless network that does not have an internet connection the above method still returns true, thus I have an extra try catch in my method. I am actually parsing custom XML files and thus cant use the RSS parser. A question though if i increment the counter in the completed event, when exactly would I need to decrement it?

Comment: Really it doesn't matter as long as it happens inside that event you should be good. Also as far as parsing the xml file it might be different, but when it comes to downloading it the method does not change.